# Passar parâmetros para uma função que está sendo passada de parâmetro pra outra

Tags: javascript, funções, callback

Imagina assim, tenho a função1 que precisa receber como parâmetro uma função *callback*.

A função 2 precisa receber um parâmetro e eu preciso passar ela como um valor da função1, como eu passaria esse valor "message" na função 2 sendo que tenho que chamar ela na 1?

```js
function funcao1(cb) {
  return cb();
}

function funcao2(message) {
  console.log(message)
}

funcao1(funcao2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível fazer exatamente isso, pode algo próximo. A assinatura da função `cb` não prevê que tenha parâmetros, então você não pode passar uma função que tenha esse parâmetro.

Uma solução é mudar `funcao()` para que `cb()` aceite parâmetro e aceite também um parâmetro para ser passado. Acho que não é o que deseja, o que o desejado não é possível.

```js
function funcao1(cb, message) {
    return cb(message);
}

function funcao2(message) {
    console.log(message);
}

funcao1(funcao2, "ok");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/CallAny.js).

Outra possibilidade é usar uma clausura, assim a mensagem vai junto:

```js
function funcao1(cb) {
  return cb();
}

var message = "ok";

function funcao2() {
  console.log(message);
}

funcao1(funcao2);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/CallAny2.js).

Isso não é exatamente uma *closure* (é uma global, enclausuraria se estivesse dentro de uma função), mas passa a ideia de como funciona, pode colocar a `funcao2()` e `message` dentro de outra função que aí fica do jeito que estou falando, até porque deve ser assim que será de fato em código real.

Ainda não deve ser o que deseja, mas são as alternativas. Pode ter novas alternativas entendendo o problema real, talvez nem precise de tudo isso. O exemplo artificial não é ruim para explicar o básico, mas não dá margem para outras alternativas.

Ainda tem a opção do user140828 em comentário abaixo:

```js
function funcao1(cb) {
    return cb();
}

function funcao2(message) {
    console.log(message);
}

funcao1(() => funcao2("ok"));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/CallAny3.js).

Você cria uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) extra, mas ainda vejo que se fizer isso pode não fazer muito sentido. Acho que precisa analisar melhor o problema real.

Comment: Eu também sugeriria utilizar `funcao1(() => funcao2('ok'))`, mas não entendi muito bem o que o autor da pergunta quer.

Comment: @user140828 boa, coloquei o crédito pra vc.